# Firefox snap downgraded to an older esr version on 22.04 with snap refresh?

Tags: firefox, 22.04, snap

Today I ran a `snap refresh`, and Firefox upgraded to an older esr version.

How is that possible?

```
snap info firefox

....
     tracking:     latest/stable
 refresh-date: today at 19:00 CET
 channels:
  latest/stable:    102.8.0esr-2 2023-02-16 (2364) 185MB -
  latest/candidate: 110.0-3      2023-02-14 (2356) 252MB -
  latest/beta:      111.0b1-1    2023-02-14 (2360) 181MB -
  latest/edge:      112.0a1      2023-02-16 (2365) 197MB -
  esr/stable:       102.7.0esr-1 2023-01-17 (2270) 183MB -
  esr/candidate:    102.8.0esr-2 2023-02-16 (2364) 185MB -
  esr/beta:         ↑                                    
  esr/edge:         ↑                                    
    installed:          102.8.0esr-2            (2364) 185MB -
```

Comment: Do you really want to know how it is possible? There are many possibilities for human error in the process. Or do you actually want to know what your options are to restore v110 or v111?

Comment: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/firefox-stable-snap-points-to-102esr/33929 for discussion on this incident.

Comment: Well, it is already fixed, thx for the fast responses.

Answer (score 3):

People notice this change (which might be unintentional) when Firefox warns them that their Profile might not work anymore.

One way to restore your previous (higher) version of the Firefox snap:

```
sudo snap revert firefox
```

Another way:

```
Today:
sudo snap refresh --candidate firefox

When fixed upstream:
sudo snap refresh --stable firefox
```

- Reminder: Backing up your Firefox profile to preserve your bookmarks and logins and extensions is always a great idea!

Comment: Thx, actually it has already been fixed upstream, so another snap refresh fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems it was an error somewhere in the system. That has been fixed.

A little patience and another `snap refresh` fixed it all.

It updated some Firefox hooks:

```
 firefox 110.0-3 from Mozilla✓ refreshed
```

All good now.